# Consul Key/value not working when acl enbled

Tags: acl, consul

When I configure Spring microservice to acl enabled consul not able to read the key/value from consul.

"acl":{
"enabled":true,
**"default_policy":"deny",**
"enable_token_persistence":true,
"down_policy": "extend-cache",
"tokens":{
"master":"72bef82a-5fdd-225e-5561-c07001492b22"
}
}

when make default_policy to allow I'm able to access the key values.

I want to make sure default_policy to deny.

Please let me know what I'm missing here? Do I need any policy to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an ACL policy which grants access to read (and optionally write) the desired KV path. For example:

```
# spring-cloud-consul-kv-policy.hcl
#
key_prefix "env/prod/app/springapp" {
  # Grant read and write permissions for the specified prefix.
  # Change to policy = 'read' if write is not needed.

  policy = "write"
}
```

Create the policy using [`consul acl policy create`](https://www.consul.io/commands/acl/policy/create).

```sh
consul acl policy create \
  -name="SpringCloudAppPolicy" \
  -description="ACL policy for my SpringCloud app" \
  -rules=@spring-cloud-consul-kv-policy.hcl
```

Then create a token and assign the privileges of this policy using [`consul acl token create`](https://www.consul.io/commands/acl/token/create).

```sh
consul acl token create -policy-name="SpringCloudAppPolicy"
```

The token's Secret ID must be set as the value of the [`spring.cloud.consul.config.acl-token`](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-consul/reference/html/appendix.html) application property in in Spring Cloud Consul (see https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-consul/reference/html/appendix.html).

After performing these steps, your application should be able to retrieve its configuration from Consul KV store using the provided ACL token.

I recommend reading https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/consul/access-control-setup-production for more information on securing Consul with ACLs.

Comment: Thank you for quick Response. Yes Tried same. still same error
ACL Config:
"acl":{
        "enabled":true,
        "default_policy":"deny",
        "enable_token_persistence":true,
  "down_policy": "extend-cache",
        "tokens":{
   "master":"72bef82a-5fdd-225e-5561-c07001492b22"
        }
    }

spring.cloud.consul.config.acl-token=7e89b276-ca56-a3e5-7029-56f1e1d669bf

used master key as config acl token.

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'testkey' in value "${testkey}"

Comment: Are there any errors being logged in Consul which would indicate why the API call from Spring Cloud is failing? The token `7e89b276-ca56-a3e5-7029-56f1e1d669bf` differs from what you have configured as the master token. Does this token exist within Consul?

Comment: yes, the key exists in master token. I found the route cause, I added the spring.cloud.consul.config.acl-token in bootstrap.properties. it worked as spring will load the bootstrap 1st. thanks for help